# Trigger that inserts multiple rows in a new table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to figure out how can I create a trigger that inserts multiple rows in another table, not just once.

I have 4 tables --> Student, Class, Assignment, ClassAssignment

```
Student: 
ID INT, CLASSID (FOREIGN KEY, references class(ID))
Class:
ID INT,
Assignment:
ID
ClassAssignment (Is a bridge table) from Class And Assignment.
```

I want, every time a new row is inserted in 'ClassAssignment', FOR EVERY STUDENT that have this 'ClassID', to insert into another table StudentAssignmentSolution, the studentID and assignmentID (both from this inserted row).

```
create trigger newClassAssignment after insert on classassignment 
for each row
insert into StudentAssignmentSolution(studentID, assignmentID) 
values((select id from student where classID = new.classID), new.assignmentID);
```

What I don't know to do, is how to make the trigger to insert multiple rows in another table, not just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` in your `INSERT INTO ...` statement, to select from the table `Student` all the students that have that specific `classID`:

```
INSERT INTO StudentAssignmentSolution(studentID, assignmentID) 
SELECT s.ID, NEW.assignmentID
FROM Student s
WHERE s.classID = NEW.classID
```